# when using rufus, Resque or whenever scheduler and what are the weaknesses and strengths of them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduler, resque, whenever

I'm a new member of ruby on rails, and i'm researching for job schedulers in rails, but i am quite confused because having many schedulers such as rufus, whenever, resque.... Could you show me some information, documents or advice ? thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

[Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com) is a good resource to know about when you are considering among various options. It shows which gems are most popular for a particular type of task.

The two categories of tools that apply to your question are [Scheduling](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling) and [Background jobs](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs)

Any of `resque`, `delayed_job`, `rufus-scheduler`, `Sidekiq`, `whenever` and other gems listed above will be able to help with the requirement, I would recommend `delayed_job` for a total beginner - as it is easy to setup and learn about.

Best to check out the [Railscasts episode on delayed_job](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job) to start with.

If you are interested in exploring the other options, it is likely there is a [Railscasts episode for that](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32).

Comment: I appreciate your recomendation, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Resque, delayed_job and Sidekiq - for background jobs through job queue.

rufus and whenever for scheduling.
Rufus runs inside application when server initilize, 'whenever' runs outside through environment when you deploying application or start it manualy. So Rufus dont work without application, but you need to keep an eye on whenever additionaly.